# C# Diccionario clave inexistente?

Tags: c#

Me duele la cabeza por no encontrar el error, es por esto que pido ayuda a alguien que se de cuenta.
Creo un diccionario con todas las combinaciones de bytes posibles, que tiene como clave una cadena de bytes, y como valor, un entero que corresponde con el índice.
Según esto, deberian estar TODAS las cadenas de bytes (de 3 bytes) posibles, pero, como escribo en mi código, al buscar cualquiera de las posibilidades, nunca la encuentra.
En el código busco una en concreto, pero he probado con muchas y tampoco, no encuentra ninguna.
Muchas gracias por anticipado

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Diccionario
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<byte[], int> tabla = new Dictionary<byte[], int>();
            int contador=1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++)
                    {
                        byte[] cadena = { (byte)i, (byte)j, (byte)k };
                        tabla.Add(cadena, contador);
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
            }
            byte[] cadenacif = { 112, 23, 0 };
            int final = tabla[cadenacif];
            Console.WriteLine(final);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tu error es que estas buscando un arreglo como clave, un arreglo es un dato por referencia, no por valor entonces si tu haces "new int[]{1} == new int[]{1}" te dara como resultado false, ya que esta verificando que la referencia de memoria sea la misma por ello siempre te dira que no existe la clave

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero...entonces como puedo almacenar y luego recuperar cadenas de bytes?

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que conviertas el arreglo de bytes en un string y usar un diccionario con clave string

Comment: Si, es buena idea, muchisimas gracias

Comment: no hay de que, para transformar un arreglo en string usa el metodo Join de la clase string

Comment: Estaba pensando en utilizar BitConverter.ToString(), pero evaluaré también Join

Comment: Considera usar una tupla para ahorrarte la conversión. Te adjunto un [gist](https://gist.github.com/JaimeMenendez/9b7150bc1978edb2411c77376395fba4) que probé y funciona. Es una estructura ligera y eficiente, y funciona por valor justo como necesitas.

Comment: WOW funciona a la perfección Jaime. Muchisimas gracias, llevaba dias atascado.

Comment: Me alegra te haya ayudado. Considera responderte a ti mismo, ahora que ya sabes la causa del problema, explicando por qué no te funcionaba y cómo lo resolviste. Intentar explicarte te ayudará a una mayor comprensión, ayudas a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema y de paso cierras la pregunta. Bienvenido a la comunidad. Recuerda también hacer [el recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ganar tus primeras medallas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en intentar acceder a una clave mediante una referencia, cuando se debe acceder por valor.

Hay dos soluciones para este caso, una almacenar las claves mediante un string, convirtiendo la matriz de bytes en string, y una vez accedido correctamente al par clave-valor, volver a convertirlo en matriz de bytes.

La segunda es una almacenar las claves mediante una tupla, que almacena valores en byte, y por tanto ya no se accede por referencia.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<byte, byte, byte>, int> tabla = new Dictionary<Tuple<byte, byte, byte>, int>();
int contador = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++)
        {
            var cadena = new Tuple<byte, byte, byte>((byte) i, (byte) j, (byte) k);
            tabla.Add(cadena, contador);
            contador++;
        }
    }
}

Tuple<byte, byte, byte> cadenatup = new Tuple<byte, byte, byte>(112, 23, 0);
int final = tabla[cadenatup];
Console.WriteLine(final);
```